# Obtain latest data from SQLite by different user using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

SQLite database name '**trans**', with the following columns below.
Number of users inserting data into this database.

Example,

```
+---------+-------+---------------+--------------------+

|ic       |Borrow |Borrow_Time    |Return_Time         |

+---------+-------+---------------+--------------------+    
|abc12    |1      |20161124160453 |20161124200543    
|def34    |1      |20161124120453 |20161124130453      
|def34    |2      |20161124160453 |20161124200453     
|abc12    |2      |20161124213845 |20161124220433     
|def34    |1      |20161124210453 |    
+---------+-------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I want to obtain the

```
|abc12    |2      |20161124213845 |20161124220433
```

and

```
|def34    |2      |20161124160453 |20161124200453
```

as they are the latest transaction done for each user.

```
|def34    |1      |20161124210453 |
```

def34 is unable to borrow until the user return what the user borrowed.

Comment: what is ic?  is that a user id?

Comment: Is that `Return_Time` NULL or an empty string? Does "latest" mean borrow or return time?

Comment: @CL. when i print in python, there's ('NONE'). Latest from the return time.

Comment: That's not what it prints; `'NONE'` would be a string with four characters.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later (older Pythons might have an older version), you can use MAX() to select a specific row in a group:

```sql
SELECT ic,
       Borrow,
       Borrow_Time,
       MAX(Return_Time) AS Return_Time
FROM trans
WHERE Return_Date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ic;
```